# Clip a single fixed position global gradient anywhere in dom

Tags: css, background-image, gradient, clip-path

I'm trying to set up an effect like Telegram's chat scrolling, where there is a global gradient positioned relative to the screen (fixed), and elements vary in color according to their vertical position on the screen.

It should look something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this in an efficient and flexible way? I considered these options:

- Using `background-attachment: fixed` and having giving all items the same background-image.
- Using `clip-path` in some manner (although I have never used this property before).

Would these work? Is there a better way?

Comment: Please could you show us the code you have tried.

Comment: I have not tried any code yet, I am still in my research phase